# Does adding window as a prefix to the global objects speed up accessing global objects?

Tags: javascript

I have seen javascript code where global objects are referenced using window as the prefix

e.g

```
window.global_object
```

Does it improve the speed of accessing those objects. 
say I have the following code

```
testGlobalObject = "some value";

function f1 () {
    function f2 () {
        function f3 () {
            console.log("testGlobalObject value="+window.testGlobalObject)
        }
        f3();
    }
    f2();
}
f1();
```

so when the function f3() is executed, since I am specifying **window** explicitly as window.testGlobalObject, will the JS engine
**start** searching the object/variable in the **window** object? Or does it still go searching as usual for the
testGlobalObject within f3, then f2 then f1 and then finally the **window** object.

Comment: Consider that it has to look for `window` anyway ... `window` is not a reserved word; it's just an identifier. It might be a local variable or it might be global.

Comment: ALL performance questions should be answered via testing and measurement.  You could create a simple [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) and get your answer.